# Drag and Drop Behavior on Chrome DevTools Protocol

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, chrome-devtools-protocol

I am trying to write a tool that open's a website and interacts with and triggers the drag/drop behavior. I am seeing `Input.dragIntercepted`, `Input.dispatchDragEvent` functions in the documentation. But when I use these functions, I am getting a **... is not a function error**. Probably, I am not using them in a proper way.

How can I use these functions to trigger drag and drop behavior of the web application? I did not find any example that shows usage of these functions.

Comment: If you could share the code you are using, I could try to reproduce and check

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `Input.dragIntercepted` really isn't a function. It's an event that will be fired, but only if you enable it, using `Input.setInterceptDrags` with `enable` set as `true`.

This is documented both [here](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Input/#method-setInterceptDrags) and [here](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Input/#event-dragIntercepted).